# Python Gtk TreeView Column Data Display

Tags: python, treeview, gtk

I have been using the code found here:

[How to limit number of decimal places to be displayed in Gtk CellRendererText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27675919/)

successfully for several years to format Treeview number columns. But when I insert columns using a loop, the columns display the data from the first column, rather than the data I would expect to get from the ListStore. Why is this? I've struggled with this for sometime and it probably is a really simple solution, but I am rather clueless!! Thank you very much. Here's a working example that shows my problem:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
    # Setup
        self.iListstore = Gtk.ListStore(str, float, float, float, float)
        self.iListstore.append(['abc',209.8967,568.56432, 1, 2])
        self.iListstore.append(['def',2409.846,559.534, 3, 4])
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.iTreeView = Gtk.TreeView(self.iListstore)
    # Column 0
        lblr= Gtk.CellRendererText()
        lcol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Row Label')
        self.iTreeView.append_column(lcol)
        lcol.pack_start(lblr, True)
        lcol.add_attribute(lblr, 'text',0)
    # Column 1
        cr = Gtk.CellRendererText(xalign=1)
        myCol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Col1')
        myCol.set_sort_column_id(1)
        self.iTreeView.append_column(myCol)
        myCol.pack_start(cr, True)
        myCol.add_attribute(cr, 'text',1)
        myCol.set_cell_data_func(cr,lambda column, cell, model, iter, unused:cell.set_property("text","{0:.2f}".format(round(model.get(iter,1)[0],2))))
    # Column 2
        myCol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Col2')
        myCol.set_sort_column_id(2)
        self.iTreeView.append_column(myCol)
        myCol.pack_start(cr, True)
        myCol.add_attribute(cr, 'text',2)
        myCol.set_cell_data_func(cr,lambda column, cell, model, iter, unused:cell.set_property("text","{0:.2f}".format(round(model.get(iter,2)[0],2))))
# The above works but the following does not. Col3 has the same value as Col4. Can someone tell me the reason a loop can not be used with the code?
        colNames=['Col3','Col4']
        for i in range(3,5):
            myCol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(colNames[i-3]) # I realize this is a bit of a fudge 
            myCol.set_sort_column_id(i)
            self.iTreeView.append_column(myCol)
            myCol.pack_start(cr, True)
            myCol.add_attribute(cr, 'text',i)
            myCol.set_cell_data_func(cr,lambda column, cell, model, iter, unused:cell.set_property("text","{0:.2f}".format(round(model.get(iter,i)[0],2))))
    # Window
            self.window.add(self.iTreeView)
            self.window.show_all()

    def main(self):
        Gtk.main()

    p=myClass()
    p.main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Lambda in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837486/python-lambda-in-a-loop)

Comment: Slightly better: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546285/creating-lambda-inside-a-loop

Comment: Libeforce   Thank you for the solution. This has really helped me understand my error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just indeed the `set_cell_data_func` is a pivotal point for formatting text in a treeviewcolumn cell. I simplified the above answer, all is done in one go via a for loop. For the real formatting you can use the new f-string feature.

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
    # Setup
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        iListstore = Gtk.ListStore(str, float, float, float, float)
        iListstore.append(['abc',209.8967,568.56432, 1, 2])
        iListstore.append(['def',2409.846,559.534, 3, 4])
        self.iTreeView = Gtk.TreeView(model=iListstore)
        self.window.add(self.iTreeView)
        treeview_columns = ['Row Label', 'Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4']
        for col_num, name in enumerate(treeview_columns):
            # align text in column cells of row (0.0 left, 0.5 center, 1.0 right)
            rendererText = Gtk.CellRendererText(xalign=1.0, editable=False)
            column = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(name ,rendererText, text=col_num)
            column.set_cell_data_func(rendererText, self.celldatafunction, func_data=col_num)
            # center the column titles in first row
            column.set_alignment(0.5)
            # make all the column reorderable, resizable and sortable
            column.set_sort_column_id(col_num)
            column.set_reorderable(True)
            column.set_resizable(True)
            self.iTreeView.append_column(column)
    # Window
        self.window.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
        self.window.show_all()

    def celldatafunction(self, col, cell, mdl, itr, i):
    # col = Columnn, cell = Cell, mdl = model, itr = iter, i = column number
    # column is provided by the function, but not used
        value = mdl.get(itr,i)[0]
        if type(value) is not str:
            cell.set_property('text',f'{value+0.005:.2f}')
        path = mdl.get_path(itr)
        row = path[0]
        colors = ['white', 'lightskyblue']
    # set alternating backgrounds
        cell.set_property('cell-background', colors[row % 2])

    def main(self):
        Gtk.main()

p = myClass()
p.main()
```

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. I'll check mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I really tried to get the lambda function going using Libeforce's links (thanks again!) but couldn't resolve it. According to [What do (lambda) function closures capture?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/),"The trick is to remember that loops do not create new scope", so the next column is never changed. I broke the function out and code now works:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk
import  inspect

class myClass:
    def __init__(self):
    # Setup
        self.iListstore = Gtk.ListStore(str, float, float, float, float)
        self.iListstore.append(['abc',209.8967,568.56432, 1, 2])
        self.iListstore.append(['def',2409.846,559.534, 3, 4])
        self.window = Gtk.Window()
        self.iTreeView = Gtk.TreeView(self.iListstore)
        self.window.add(self.iTreeView) # moved to avoid an error of adding TreeView twice to Window
    # Column 0
        lblr= Gtk.CellRendererText()
        lcol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Row Label')
        self.iTreeView.append_column(lcol)
        lcol.pack_start(lblr, True)
        lcol.add_attribute(lblr, 'text',0)
    # Column 1
        cr = Gtk.CellRendererText(xalign=1)
        myCol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Col1')
        myCol.set_sort_column_id(1)
        self.iTreeView.append_column(myCol)
        myCol.pack_start(cr, True)
        myCol.add_attribute(cr, 'text',1)
        myCol.set_cell_data_func(cr,lambda column, cell, model, iter, unused:cell.set_property("text","{0:.2f}".format(round(model.get(iter,1)[0],2))))
    # Column 2
        myCol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn('Col2')
        myCol.set_sort_column_id(2)
        self.iTreeView.append_column(myCol)
        myCol.pack_start(cr, True)
        myCol.add_attribute(cr, 'text',2)
        myCol.set_cell_data_func(cr,lambda column, cell, model, iter, unused:cell.set_property("text","{0:.2f}".format(round(model.get(iter,2)[0],2))))
# The above works and the following now works. Could not figure out how to use lambda properly so broke the function out into roundCell
        colNames=['Col3','Col4']
        for i in range(3,5):
            myCol = Gtk.TreeViewColumn(colNames[i-3])
            myCol.set_sort_column_id(i)
            self.iTreeView.append_column(myCol)
            myCol.pack_start(cr, True)
            myCol.add_attribute(cr, 'text',i)
            myCol.set_cell_data_func(cr, self.roundCell,i)
    # Window
            self.window.show_all()

    def roundCell(self, col, myCell, mdl, itr,i):
        # col =Columnn, myCell = Cell, mdl = model, itr = inter, i = column number
        # We don't use column, but it is provided by the function
        myCell.set_property("text","{0:.2f}".format(round(mdl.get(itr,i)[0],2)))

    def main(self):
        Gtk.main()

p=myClass()
p.main()
```